# Zabbix: how to read a remote file

Tags: zabbix

In Zabbix we can read a files like that:

```
vfs.file.time[/path/file.txt]
```

I need to now how to read a file in a remote path, like this:

`vfs.file.time[\\server\path\file.txt`

Thanks

Comment: Is this about Windows? Given that network mapping is not directly supported, you'd probably have to use external checks, user parameters or a similar approach.

Comment: Create a .bat file to check the date of the file, configure this bat with userparameter in zabbix_agentd.conf